# HTTPS GET in nodejs body

Tags: node.js, https

im new in nodejs and Im having some problems with https.
Im using google safe browsing lookup API.
At this moment I have a test (with jasmine) and a "test" route with express, since I only have backend Im using postman to see how my routes works and see the replies from my server.
So whtats my problem, better I show you the code.

Here is my "test" route:

```
apiRoutes.route('/test').
//Just for postman manually test
get(function(req, res){
    appFunctions.safeBrowser('http://www.38zu.cn',function(callback){
        res.send(callback);
    });
```

Here the function safeBrowser:

```
var safeBrowser = function(urlToCheck, callback){

    if(urlToCheck.toString().substring(0,7) === "http://"){
        var apikey = config.APIKEY
        var url = "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=DimGray&key="+apikey+"&appver=1&pver=3.1&url="+urlToCheck;

        https.get(url, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                callback(d);
            });
        }).on('error', function(error){
            callback("error 1"); //For the moment, must change
        });
    }
    else
        callback("error 2");  //For the moment, must change

}
```

And here my jasmine test

```
    it("check a malware url should return malware", function(done) {
    var malwareUrl = 'http://www.38zu.cn';
    appFunctions.safeBrowser(malwareUrl, function(callback){
        expect(callback).toBe('malware');
        done();
    });
});
```

When I use postman to manually test the route "/test" postman (GET) retun me

```
malwaree
```

But when I pass the test, taht what I get:

```
     1) CeckStatus check a malware url should return malware
   Message:
     Expected { 0 : 109, 1 : 97, 2 : 108, 3 : 119, 4 : 97, 5 : 114, 6 : 101 } to be 'malware'.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected { 0 : 109, 1 : 97, 2 : 108, 3 : 119, 4 : 97, 5 : 114, 6 : 101 } to be 'malware'.
    at D:\GitRepository\UrlShortener2015\dimGray\spec\safeBrowserSpec.js:16:30
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\GitRepository\UrlShortener2015\dimGray\backend\handlers\functions.js:38:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:360:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:743:26)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:723:3)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)
```

I really dont know why postman return me 'malware' and the test that extrange JSON

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like callback might be a blob?

Try `expect(callback.toString()).toBe('malware');`

Comment: or you can test it here too: `res.on('data', function(d) { callback(d.toString()); });`